# array compile time initialisation

Tags: c++

I wrote this program but it is showing error

> details was not declared in this scope.

How can I correct this code?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class dealer
{
    private:
    char first_name[30],last_name[30],city[20],phone_number[20];
    public:
        void accept()
        {
            details[0].first_name:"Simran"; 
            details[1].first_name:"Palak";
            details[0].last_name:"Arora";
            details[1].last_name:"Kaur";
            details[0].city:"Amritsar";
            details[1].city:"Jalandhar";
            details[0].phone_number:1234567890;
            details[1].phone_number:8987654321;
        }
        void display()
        {
            cout<<"Record of first person"<<endl;
            cout<<"First name is "<<details[0].first_name<<endl;
            cout<<"Last name is "<<details[0].last_name<<endl;
            cout<<"City is "<<details[0].city<<endl;
            cout<<"Phone number is "<<details[0].phone_number<<endl;

            cout<<"Record of second person"<<endl;
            cout<<"First name is "<<details[1].first_name<<endl;
            cout<<"Last name is "<<details[1].last_name<<endl;
            cout<<"City is "<<details[1].city<<endl;
            cout<<"Phone number is "<<details[1].phone_number<<endl;
        }
    };
        int main()
        {
            dealer details[2];
            details[0].accept();
            details[1].accept();
            details[0].display();
            details[1].display();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `details` variable is not declared in your code.

Comment: please tell me how to do that as details is a user defined data type variable?

Comment: I cannot since I don't understand why you mean by `"details" is a user-defined variable` - Please read: [ask] and [edit] your question by improving it.

Comment: Any reason to not use `std::string`?

Comment: `details[0].first_name:"Simran"; ` This is not valid C++ code. Where did you pick it up? Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: You seem to be trying to access various elements of an array of `dealer`, that's declared in `main`... from within the definition of `dealer`. That's inside out. Why have you done it this way? What are you trying to achieve? How can we give you the solution when we don't know what the program's supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to access `details` within `Dealer::accept()`. However, `details` is a variable local to your `main()` function. `Dealer::accept()` is a member of the `Dealer` class and can only see member variables declared within that class.

`Dealer` cannot see the variable `details` that you've declared in `main()`. If you want the `Dealer` class to initialize certain members, consider writing functions to set those specific variables. For instance, to set `first_name`, write a function like:

```
void Dealer::setFirstName(std::string name)
{
    strcpy(first_name, name.c_str()); // Consider changing the type of first_name to 
                                      // std::string. No need to use char arrays in this 
                                      // day and age
}

int main() 
{
    dealer details[2];
    details[0].setFirstName("Simran");
    details[1].setFirstName("Palak");
    // etc...
}
```